# Ошибка при попытке установить captcha в форму

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь установить captcha в форму.
Выполняю команду `pip install django-simple-captcha`.

Добавляю приложение captcha в список зарегестрированных приложений:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'captcha',
]
```

Выполнил миграции.
Перехожу в urls.py на уровне проекта, и дополняю список записью:`path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('home.urls')),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', views.HomeLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.HomeLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/password_change/', views.HomePasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('accounts/password_change/done', views.HomePasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    path('accounts/password_reset/', views.HomePasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('accounts/password_reset/done/', views.HomePasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.HomePasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('accounts/reset/done/', views.HomePasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Обновляю форму

```
...
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    rubric = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Rubrics.objects.all())
    author = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all())
    captcha = CaptchaField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'rubric', 'author', 'captcha')
```

Код шаблона:

```
{% extends 'home/layout/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}
        {{ form.content }}
        {{ form.rubric }}
        {{ form.author }}
        {{ form.captcha }}
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить запись">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

А вот используемое представление:

```
class HomeCreateView(CreateView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'home/create.html'
    success_url = '/home/'
    fields = ('title', 'content', 'rubric', 'author', 'captcha')
```

При открытие формы ничего не меняется, то есть captcha не появляется. В терминале ввожу команду `python3 manage.py test captcha`, возвращается ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfixtures'`

Comment: это полный код из вашей формы ? И как выводите форму в шаблон?

Comment: я дополнил полным кодом формы и шаблона